# Using Leaflet with WMTS server?

Tags: javascript, gis, leaflet

Is it possible to use [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/) javascript library to show map data from a [WMTS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wmts) (Web Map Tile Service) based server? Leaflet doesn't seem to support WMTS out of the box, but are there any plugins for that?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the L.TileLayer.WMTS class as implemented here:
http://depot.ign.fr/geoportail/api/develop/tech-docs-js/examples/js/geoportalLeaflet.js

Here is the result: http://depot.ign.fr/geoportail/api/develop/tech-docs-js/examples/geoportalLeaflet.html

Comment: Am I right that is is only working with KVP encoding ? not REST ? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Tile_Service). I'm trying to use it with https://api3.geo.admin.ch/api/

Comment: these links are broken :( - any chance someone can update the answer with embedded solutions or updated links?